# Getting month from Date.today

Tags: ruby

How do you get the month as an integer from the below code

```
3.2.21@2.1.3 (#<VouchersController:0x007ff453)> t = (Date.today + 5).to_s
=> "2015-12-01"
3.2.21@2.1.3 (#<VouchersController:0x007ff453)> t.to_i
=> 2015
3.2.21@2.1.3 (#<VouchersController:0x007ff453)>
```

I can get the year. But how do I get the month as an integer so this returns `12`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're getting the year is only that you're converting the string `"2015-12-01"` to an integer.

When you use `to_i` on a Ruby string, it uses only leading digit characters, then throws away the rest of the string. When it reaches the first `-` character, it stops parsing as an integer and returns what it has so far: `2015`.

In order to use the actual functionality of `Date`, don't use `to_s` to convert the object into a string.

```
require 'date'
t = Date.today + 5 # => #<Date: 2015-11-30 ((2457357j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
t.year             # => 2015
t.month            # => 11
```